# Flutter - firebase dynamic linking preview image gets rotated in some apps

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have integrated deep linking in Flutter using firebase_dynamic_links. I have passed url of image in socialMetaTagParameters as below given code. But the issue is in some apps like Skype, Whatsapp some images get rotated in the preview even if image url gives portrait image. I am not sure what wrong is going on. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'xxxxxx',
      link: Uri.parse('xxxxxx'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'xxx.xxxx.xxxx',
        minimumVersion: 0,
      ),
      dynamicLinkParametersOptions: DynamicLinkParametersOptions(
        shortDynamicLinkPathLength: ShortDynamicLinkPathLength.short,
      ),
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: 'xxx.xxxx.xxxx',
        minimumVersion: '0',
        appStoreId: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
      ),
      socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
          title: 'MyApp',
          description: 'about',
          imageUrl: Uri.parse(imageUrl)),
    );

    final ShortDynamicLink shortLink = await parameters.buildShortLink();
    Uri url = shortLink.shortUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

> some images get rotated in the preview even if image url gives portrait image.

Looking at [this firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews), you will find that "The image should be at least 300x200 px". Meaning, images should have a longer width than height in order to fit the normal link preview style in apps. That is why your image gets rotated.